# displaying the html entities in php code

Tags: php, html

How to display the input type elements in the php code in the same page

I am trying this code but it is not working

HTML

```
<html>
<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywordsid" value="sample keyword" />
</html>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
echo $kewords;
    ?>
```

To display html input type fields in the php code what should we do?

Comment: are you serious :o , you want to get the input value in PHP right ?

Comment: Look up how to submit a form using PHP.

Comment: If what you want is to show the content of the input, that is better suited by Javascript. If you want to handle the information on the server side refer to [Dealing with Forms at PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya : Yes,I tried $_POST['keywords'] but it's not working

Comment: @ShobhanBabu check my answer , replace the form action with your php file name

Comment: you can also action leave blank then page don't redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use PHP pre defined `$_SERVER` variable :**

[$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywordsid" value="sample keyword" />

    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    if(isset( $_POST['keywords']))
     {
        echo $_POST['keywords'];
     }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here, `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` helps you to get result on the same page without sending the request to another page.

Answer (score 2):

index.php  file

```
<html>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywordsid" value="sample keyword" />
    <input typ="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </html>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['keywords']))
    {
       $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
       echo $keywords;
    }

?>
```

Comment: I don't want forward these values into another page rather I want display it in the same html file..

Comment: @ShobhanBabu to write php and html in a same file , the file type shoul be .php , change your html file to a php file , then give that name to the form action

Comment: if you want to get result on same page then leave action blank like action="" and write php code ate the same page or file then you do not redirect to another page

Comment: @Prabhash that can be also Done :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all without form you dont get input type field name in php.
so, use form and after submmit form you are using $_POST['keywords'] instead of  $kewords to echo input field name.

Comment: @ShobhanBabu yh because you are not using a form or doing anything with it! You have just done an input!

Comment: Please check comment again. You are not using Form. without submit form you dont echo value of input fields.

Answer (score 0):

let, your page url is index.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywordsid" value="sample keyword" />

<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset( $_POST['keywords']))
echo $_POST['keywords'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want forward these values into another page rather I want display it in the same html file.. –

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<html>
 <form action ="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywordsid" value="sample keyword" />
<input type="submit">
</html>
```

and write php code

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['keywords']))
   {
    echo $_POST['keywords'];
    }
?>
```

This is the way to write php and html

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code bellow to echo the keywords.

```
<?php
echo '<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywordsid" value="'.$keywords.'" />';
?>
```